# Unable to install linux respin in debian 9

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to install a .deb file in Debian 9 and I do this:

```
# sudo apt install ./respin-2.0.1.deb
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file ./respin-2.0.1.deb given on commandline
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: It appears you do not have that file. Are you sure that the file exists? use `find / -name "respin-2.0.1.deb"`. If it does not show up then you do not have that file on your system.

Comment: it says: find: ‘/run/user/117/gvfs’: Permission denied

Comment: @lebro111 What does? The find command? are your still root? If the .deb file is located in `/root/Desktop/LinuxRespin-master/` you can run `find /root/Desktop/LinuxRespin-master/ -name "respin-2.0.1.deb"` It very much is looking like you do not actually have the .deb file. Re-download it and run `dpkg -i [Package Name].deb` Update your post with the results and add a link if you are following a guide or forum post.

Comment: find /root/Desktop/LinuxRespin-master/ -name "respin-2.0.1.deb" is it good that it did nothing or should it have an output?

Comment: dpkg -i [Package Name].deb

Comment: dpkg -i respin-2.0.1.deb

did not work

Comment: Does the `deb` file provide a package that is actually for your architecture? What does `dpkg -i ./respin.deb` say?

Comment: i am in 64bit and it works with both

Comment: Well, there are 64 bit ARM processors, and there are 64 bit AMD processors...

Comment: Unsupported file ./respin-2.0.1.deb : Provides e.g. `CONTENTS/usr/lib/respin/EFI/BOOT/{bootia32.efi, bootx64.efi, grubx64.efi}` and `CONTENTS/usr/bin/{bash scripts}` https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package’s file name is invalid, which is why `apt` fails to process it. To fix this, proceed as follows (starting from scratch):

```
wget https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin/raw/master/respin-2.0-1.deb
mv respin-2.0-1.deb respin_2.0-1.deb
apt install ./respin_2.0-1.deb
```

However this won’t work on Debian 9 because the dependencies can’t be satisfied; the package is only usable on Ubuntu (despite the author’s comments to the contrary).

Comment: thx, man i will look at a different tool.

Comment: do you know of any tools i can use?

Comment: To create a live CD of your installation? Sorry, I don’t...

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like the file does not exist... Please post more details as per Stephen's comment.

If you are using a graphical session as root (which you should not), then you won't need sudo. The correct command to install your .deb is as you stated `dpkg -i <deb file>`.

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Using the older version respin-deb_1.0.0-1_all.deb, I got to next levels. Not sure if i'll be succesful, though. But the script gave me a nice custom-live.iso.

Had to do some troubleshooting though, the main editing the script "respin" in usr/bin/ after this error message:
sed: can't read /lib/live/config/1100-policykit: No such file or directory

On my system the file is "1080-policykit". So finding the lines with 1100- and changing that in 1080, works like a charm.

What I don't seem to get working is booting the dd'd usb stick. USB seems non-bootable (invisible) in my macbookair startup screen. Something to do with missing /boot or /boot/efi probably. Keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

fix broken dependencies - then respin works on Debian.

-f 
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html

feel free to ping contact at linuxrespin.org

Comment: This answer doesn't contain any commands to address the question. What's the `-f` for, and why the link to `apt-get`?